# Verifying app links: removed assetlinks.json from host yet links still verify and open to the app

Tags: android, firebase, android-app-indexing, android-app-links

Followed https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations.html and set up app link to open app from google. According to this link

```
https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?
   source.web.site=https://domain.name:optional_port&
   relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls
```

the assetlinks.json file was never deployed to the .NET application properly. Yet when I removed the assetlinks.json the app will still open to the app. Is there even a need for the assetlinks file? or is this all just an app change?

Answer (score 0):

First go to your app settings --> set as defaults --> Go to supported URLs then check which option is checked *In this app* or any other option.

"In this app" will open the app.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your intent-filter is defining which links to open in the app because of which even if your assetlinks.json is not configured, app is handling those URL.

Now, why do we need assetlinks.json?
Ans: The assetlink.json file is the part of Digital Asset Links protocol ([Google Digital Asset Links](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started)), which allows website owners to link URLs with the native app. It also helps in sharing credentials with other websites.

In short, this file will help google search to navigate traffic to the app by marking it as a trusted source.